# How to put resources under resource with Codeigniter Phil Sturgeon/Chris Kacerguis REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

I would like to do something like this: `GET api/companies/3/employees/45`.

**Solution 1**

I guess `api` would be the controller, `companies` the resource and `employees/45` the parameter. But how can I specify it is the company with id=3?

**Solution 2**

Or maybe `api` would be the controller (with index resource) and I could use `companies/3` and `employees/45` as parameters.
For `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` I can retrieve the parameters with:

```
$this->get('blah'); // GET param
$this->post('blah'); // POST param
$this->put('blah'); // PUT param
```

But `DELETE` is different and cannot be use in the same way:

```
public function index_delete($id)
{
    $this->response([
        'returned from delete:' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

So how can I do `DELETE api/companies/3` and `DELETE api/companies/3/employees/45` ?

**Solution 3**

Any other suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter helps you do that using routes. Goto application > config > routes.php
Add a line like this

```
$route['api/companies/(:num)/employees/(:num)']['GET'] = 'Test/do_stuff/$1/$2';
```

What this translates to is, when you make a request to `api/companies/3/employees/45` codeigniter will match the above route and will goto a controller called `Test` which has a function called `do_stuff` and pass the comapany id and employee id as parameters so it would look like this.

```
function do_stuff_get($company_id, $company_id)
{
    $this->response(array($company_id, $company_id));
}
```

The ['GET'] part in the routes specifies that it should match for a GET request,
you could write a different rule for a POST request and call a different function.

The (:num) specifies that it expects a number, you can also specify (:any).

In your case if you want to perform delete based on urls then you need to take into consideration the order and the request type.
In the routes.php file, the first rule that matches the request that has come in will be taken and others will be ignored.

So for the delete operations your routes.php would look like this

```
$route['api/companies/(:num)']['DELETE'] = 'Test/delete_company/$1';
$route['api/companies/(:num)/employees/(:num)']['DELETE'] = 'Test/delete_employee/$1/$2';
```

So if you wanted to delete a company and made a request to `DELETE api/companies/3` it would match the first rule and goto the function `delete_company` and the function would have a parameter which was the number that was passed in the url, for the second case of deleting an employee it would match the second rule and goto the function `delete_employee`.

For more information about routing check [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. I implemented it and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct if you worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You check if employees are included in the request then pass it to a function example below

```
public function index_delete($id = NULL, $child = NULL, $child_value = NULL)
{
    switch ($child) {
      case NULL:
        $this->delete_company($id);
        break;
      case 'employee':
        $this->delete_employee($id, $child_value);
        break;
      default:
        // some error
   }


}

public function delete_company($company_id){}
public function delete_employee($company_id, $employee_id){}
```

So what will happen here are the following:

- `api/companies/1` : it will go to `delete_company` function to delete the company 1
- `api/companies/1/employees/45` : it will go to `delete_employee` function to delete the employee 45 in company 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally implemented the Jude Fernandez’s solution, but I think yours would have worked too.